# rmdir, open_basedir и glob - странное поведение

Tags: php

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testdir';
$filetext = file_get_contents(__FILE__);
unlink(__FILE__);
rmdir($root);
mkdir($root, 0777);
file_put_contents(__FILE__, $filetext);
clearstatcache();
$iterator = new GlobIterator($root.'/*.sql');
print_r($iterator);
```

Есть файл с таким кодом. Он удаляет себя и папку, в которой находится, после чего создаёт ту же папку и такой же файл.. При этом возникает

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with
>   message 'GlobIterator::__construct(): open_basedir restriction in
>   effect.

Если папку не удалять/создавать, то open_basedir совершенно не мешает.
Кто сталкивался с подобным? Как решить? Спасибо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846882/open-basedir-restriction-in-effect-file-is-not-within-the-allowed-paths

Comment: К сожалению, это никак не относится к случаю выше. Отключение же open_basedir проблему решает, но для одного конкретного сайта одной хостинг-площадки.